# How to return a promis in a function that calls an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, promise

I have a function that call an API and I want it to return a Promise so I can know when it has finished executing

here is my Component where I call the function

```
import { login } from "../../redux/apiCalls";
...
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   login(email, password, dispatch);
   history.push('/admin');
}
```

and here is the function itself (I use redux here)

```
export const login = async (email, password, dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch(loginStart());
        const res = await axios.post('myserver...', {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        });
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch(loginError());
    }
}
```

Comment: `handleLogin` is async. You can await the login function. `await login` and wrap it in a try/catch

Comment: `const loginResp = await login(email, password, dispatch);`

Answer (score 3):

using async make by default this behavior, the function return a promise, await or not so you can this

```
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   await login(email, password, dispatch);
   history.push('/admin');
}
```

in case of error you will have to options the try catch inside the async function

```
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   try {
     await login(email, password, dispatch);
     history.push('/admin');
   } catch(err) {console.log("Hey this is an error baby ;)", err)}
}
```

but i really don't like the idea of waiting for promise since javascript is single thread so I recommand to use .then() .catch()

```
const handleLogin = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   return login(email, password, dispatch).then(() => {
     history.push('/admin');
   }).catch(console.log);
}
```

here the thread isn't blocking but maybe you want it blocking so ... up to you

Comment: The only issue with this is what if the login fails? Won't the user still be forwarded to `/admin`?

Comment: you can use a try catch but for this I strongly recommand to use .then() .catch() I will update my post and explain why

Comment: (just to note, I'm not the asker)